# Interval based API access and processing different DSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

**Background**

I'm currently working on a small Rails 5 project that needs to access and process an external API. There is a ruby wrapper gem available for the API, so accessing the data is not a problem.

**Problem description**

There are two parts of the equation that I am currently missing, and hoping someone out there can help me with.

1: I need to call the API, via Rails, every 15 minutes. How can I realize this? I was looking towards Active Job for this, but my research kind of stalled after getting no useful results.

2: The external API has different domain models and a different domain-specific language than my application. How can I map the different models without changes in Active Record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: I need to call the API, via Rails, every 15 minutes. How can I realize this? I was looking towards Active Job for this, but my research kind of stalled after getting no useful results.

The first problem you can solve using recurring tasks. The main idea is to run the process that will perform some operations every x minutes (or days or whatever fits your problem.

There are several tools that you can use. One of them is built-in the unix system and it is [cron](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab). You can read about it in system's manual. You can easily manage it using [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). The main disadvantage is that you need an access to the system's cron which may be non-trivial on non-bare machines (for example Platform as a Service hosts such as Heroku).

You should also take a look at [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) which does not rely on the system's cron. It uses approach where you have a separate process running all time and it keeps an eye on defined tasks.

In the second approach (having a separate process) you need to remember that time-consuming instructions may "lock" the process and postpone another tasks. In this case, you may want to use background processing such as [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). The idea is to use one process for scheduling tasks at certain time and another process to process those tasks as soon as they appear in the queue.

> 2: The external API has different domain models and a different domain-specific language than my application. How can I map the different models without changes in Active Record?

You need to create a client that will consume the API and map its responses into models that you have in your application. This way, you don't need to make your model's scheme dependent on the API scheme. Take a look at [resource_kit](https://github.com/digitalocean/resource_kit) gem - this is a sample solution that uses this approach.

Comment: Hey @smefju, 
**Tasks**
I've chosen 'rufus-scheduler' as my job/scheduling system. I only run one task, every 15 minutes. Locking shouldn't be a problem. Processing isn't very heavy with this API. 

The job mainly checks whether there are changes to the data. If there are changes, they should be processed. I've implemented it so far, and it works great.

**Models**
The JSON I get back from the external API gets parsed by a gem that I worked on, so my resulting data is a ruby array with hashes.

I'm currently looking to just extract the data I want and create a new object from there.

Comment: I'm only trying to work out now how to make it all look neat.

Anyway, thanks @smefju!

Answer (score 0):

HI hdauven,

1. processing the API every 15 minutes will affect your server performance,so done it by using [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), it is a background job and use [sidetiq](https://github.com/endofunky/sidetiq) it will help you to perform the task every 15 min automatically
2. You are accessing API, Then why are you worrying about different domain.

Comment: The API has some quirks in their JSON scheme that makes them hard to map to my models.

Some data needs to be discarded and some needs to be restructured.

Comment: The sidetiq/sidekiq combination doesn't seem to work with my Ruby and Rails versions. Instead I'm opting for either rufus-scheduler or Crono.

Comment: Processing tasks will not affect server performance. It may lock the process when task is being processing. The main problem is not using background processing but using recurring tasks.

Comment: yes rufus-scheduler is based on internal clock system better than cron

Comment: you want to map the json data into your using somparsers like 1)a=JSON.parse(json data) 
2)a.map (|k,v| k.to_sum: vto_s) like that

Comment: The parsing is already done by a ruby gem I worked on. :)
So it is only a matter of extracting the keys I need and mapping them to a new object.
Thanks for the reply @vinodrey!